# How to get number of messages in queue with node-amqp

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using node-amqp as a queueing system in a node application. I'd like to be able to monitor the state of the queue to figure out if we have enough workers runnning, i.e. if the queue size is increasing we know we are starting to fall behind.

I know that from the command line you can use something like;

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

Which gives me the exact information I need, but I was wondering if there is anyway to do this from node-amqp itself?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In the end, I just used the command line tool rabbitmqctl to get the information I need, its not a great solution but here is what I did;

```
var Logger = require('arsenic-logger');

getQueueMeta(function(info){
    Logger.info(info);
});

/**
* Returns a sparse array with the queue names as the indices
* and the number of messages as the value, e.g.;
*
* info = [ my-queue: 9, my-other-queue: 1 ]
* 
* @param callback
*/
function getQueueMeta(callback){

    var sys = require('sys')
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec("/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues", function(error, stdout, stderr) {

        var info = [];

        if (!error){

            var lines = stdout.split(/\n/);

            if (lines.length > 1){

                for (var i=1; i<lines.length-2; i++){
                    var temp = lines[i].split(/\s/);
                    info[temp[0].trim()] = parseInt(temp[1]);
                }

            }

        }

        callback(info);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be a bit late for the party, but in case anyone in the future stumbles across this problem... In current version of **node-amqp** (0.2.4) you can check both message count and number of currently subscribed consumers when declaring a queue.

```
var connection = require("amqp").createConnection();
connection.exchange("exampleExchange", {/*...*/}, function(exchange) {
  connection.queue("exampleQueue", {/*...*/}, function(queue, messageCount, consumerCount){
    console.log("Message count", messageCount);
    console.log("Consumer count", consumerCount);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why but I'm using version 0.5.2 and it doesn't expose those properties.

Comment: @HoangTrinh sorry, node-amqp library on NPM used to point to this repository and my comment was referring to it: https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp

Comment: This works, but I needed to set "passive: true" inside the queue option.

Answer (score 0):

So RabbitMQ supports AMQP up to 0.9.1. You can see the docs directly [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html).

A quick scan through the docs will reveal that AMQP only covers things like connections, exchanges and basic queuing / dequeuing. However many feature in `rabbitmqctl` are simply not accessible via AMQP spec. In that way `rabbitmqctl` is much closer to a "management" tool where the AMQP connection is basically a "consumer" tool.

That stated, you may be in luck. Take a look at the `connection.queue()` [method](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#queue).

```
var q = connection.queue('my-queue', function (queue) {
  console.log('Queue ' + queue.name + ' is open');
});
```

In the .NET implementation it looks like that `queue` variable includes not just the name, but also the Count of Consumers and Messages. I'm not clear what's available in the node.js, you may have to dig in.

Comment: Thanks, looking at the source code for node-amqp and inspecting the queue object sadly there is no message or consumer count (that I can see)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the code in node-AMQP and it's not populating. That stated, if the .NET and Java libraries are capable of pulling it, it's quite likely that the data exists and is simply not being exposed.